# Unable to connect to any loadbalanced web server in network when one fails

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webserver, round-robin

I have a network of one load balanced server (using nginx) *lb1* which routes traffic between four web servers *web1*, *web2*, *web3*, *web4*. These four webservers are routed to using round-robin in nginx.

All servers are set to **max_fails=1** and **fail_timeout=5s**, so when a server is down, it should be ignored fairly quickly if it is not online.

I should note that the average response time of the web pages from each web servers is around 50-150ms, if all four web servers are online. The issue arises when just ONE web server is offline. When one goes offline and a user tries to load another page, the response time varies anywhere from 50ms-25s. Yes, 25 **seconds**.

I am confused, because I would think that the round-robin and fail_timeout settings would make it so the offline server would be ignored.

Additional, possibly relevant notes: All four web servers are running apache with php5, and memcached is enabled between the four.

Comment: This might be better asked over in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Jacob is there a way to have this question moved there? Or can I just copy and paste the content to a new question on there?

Comment: I have no idea if you can move it... I'd just copy and paste it.